# An app with Retrofit 2 crashes while posting data to Mysql

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm developing an android application which need to posting and getting data to `mysql` db with `php`. Right now i am trying to sign up a user to application. I have created 2 `php` classes **Connection** and **insertUser**. With Postman i can successfully insert data to database. But when i try on the physical phone, it crashes. My code builds without error and till i press `SignUp` button it works fine. I can not see where i am making mistake. Please help.

I have added my dependencies.

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
```

Connection.php for connecting my localhost XAMPP Phpmyadmin.

```
<?php

    class Connection{
        function getConnection(){
            $host       = "localhost";
            $username   = "root";
            $password   = "root";
            $dbname     = "activityplanner_db";
            try{
                $conn    = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $conn;
            }catch (PDOException $e){
                echo "ERROR CONNECTIONF : " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

insertUser.php for inserting user info to database.

```
<?php

require_once('Connection.php');
class insertUser{
    function startInsertUser(){
        $connection = new Connection();
        $conn = $connection->getConnection();
        //array for json response
        $response = array();
        $Lastname = $_POST['LastName'];
        $Firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
        $Email = $_POST['User_Email'];
        $Mobilephone = $_POST['MobilePhone'];
        $Ssn = $_POST['SSN'];
        $Password = $_POST['User_Password'];
        $City = $_POST['User_City'];
        $JobTittle = $_POST['User_Job'];
        $BirthDate = $_POST['User_BirthDate'];
        $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];

        if($Lastname == '' || $Firstname == '' || $Email == '' || $Mobilephone == '' || $Ssn == '' || $Password == '' || $City == '' || $JobTittle == '' || 
        $BirthDate == ''){
        echo 'All fields required';
    }
        try{
            if(isset($Email) && isset($Ssn)){
                $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user (LastName, FirstName, User_Email, MobilePhone, SSN, User_Password,
                 User_City, User_Job, User_BirthDate, Gender) VALUES ('$Lastname', '$Firstname', '$Email', '$Mobilephone', '$Ssn', '$Password', 
                    '$City','$JobTittle', '$BirthDate', '$Gender')";
                $conn->exec($sqlInsert);
            }
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error while inserting ".$e->getMessage();
        }
        //cek is the row was inserted or not
        if($sqlInsert){
            //success inserted
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "User successful inserted!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
            //failed inserted
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Failed while insert data";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
$insert = new insertUser();
$insert->startInsertUser();;
?>
```

`LoggingInterceptors`.java to see the output of the process displaying data. If there is an error, this class file know what the causes of the error. T

```
public class LoggingInterceptors implements Interceptor{

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException{
        Request request = chain.request();
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        String requestLog = String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
                request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers());

        if (request.method().compareToIgnoreCase("post") == 0){
            requestLog = "\n" + requestLog + "\n" + bodyToString(request);
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "request" + "\n" + requestLog);
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        String responseLog = String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
                response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers());

        String bodyString = response.body().string();
        Log.d("TAG", "response" + "\n" + responseLog + "\n" + bodyString);

        return response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), bodyString))
                .build();
    }

    public static String bodyToString(final Request request){
        try{
            final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            copy.body().writeTo(buffer);

            return buffer.readUtf8();
        }catch (final IOException e){
            return "did not work";
        }
    }
}
```

My `URLs.java` Api Client for `Retrofit Client`.

```
public class URLs {

    public static final String URL = "http://192.168.43.172/activityplanner_php/";
```

//this my ipv4 ip when i connect my pc to my phone's hotspot.
        public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

```
    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptors())
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

And my RegisterApi interface

```
public interface RegisterAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/activityplanner_php/insertUser.php")
    Call<User> insertUser(@Field("LastName") String LastName, @Field("FirstName") String FirstName,
                          @Field("User_Email") String User_Email, @Field("MobilePhone") long MobilePhone,
                          @Field("SSN") String SSN, @Field("User_Password") String User_Password,
                          @Field("User_City") String User_City, @Field("User_Job") String User_Job,
                          @Field("User_BirthDate") Date User_BirthDate, @Field("Gender") String Gender);
}
```

My user response model.

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private int status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    public User(int status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }    
}
```

And my SignUpActivity .

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etLastName, etFirstName, etEmail, etMobilePhone, etSsn, etPassword, etCity, etJob, etBirthDate;
    RadioGroup rgGender;
    Spinner spUserType;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        Button btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignUp);
        etBirthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBirthDate);
        etLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
        etFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etMobilePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        etSsn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSSN);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
        etJob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etJob);
        rgGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGender);
        spUserType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spUserRole);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                insertUser();
            }
        });


    }
    /*public void GoToLoginActivity(View v) {
        insertUser();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/


    private void insertUser(){
        progressDialog.show();

        String firstName = etFirstName.getText().toString();
        String lastName = etLastName.getText().toString();
        String u_Email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        int radioButtonId = rgGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View radioButton = rgGender.findViewById(radioButtonId);
        int idx = rgGender.indexOfChild(radioButton);
        RadioButton rbGender = (RadioButton)rgGender.getChildAt(idx);

        String gender = rbGender.getText().toString();
        Long mobilePhone =Long.parseLong(etMobilePhone.getText().toString());
        String ssn = etSsn.getText().toString();
        String u_City = etCity.getText().toString();
        Date birthDate =Date.valueOf(etBirthDate.getText().toString());
        String u_Job = etJob.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        insertData(firstName,lastName,u_Email,gender,mobilePhone,ssn,u_City,birthDate,u_Job,password);
    }
        private void insertData(String firstName, String lastName, String u_Email, String gender,
                Long mobilePhone, String ssn, String u_City, Date birthDate, String u_Job, String password){

            RegisterAPI registerAPI = URLs.getClient().create(RegisterAPI.class);
            Call<User> call = registerAPI.insertUser(firstName, lastName, u_Email, mobilePhone, ssn, password,
                    u_City, u_Job, birthDate, gender);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    User user =response.body();

                    if(user.getStatus()==1){
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

}
```

My activity_sign_up.xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/OpeningBackground"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Widget"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

    <ScrollView
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="200dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etBirthDate"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/birthDate"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etJob" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSSN" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPhone"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etEmail" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etName"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="179dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLastName"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="182dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/lName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etLastName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSSN"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/ssn"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPhone" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etCity"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/city"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPassword" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etJob"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/Job"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etCity" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spUserRole"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TextView.SpinnerItem"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="175dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/user_role"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tUser_Role_Hint"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tUser_Role_Hint"
                android:layout_width="364dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/user_role_hint"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etBirthDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bSignUp"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/OpeningBackground"
                android:text="@string/btnSignUp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="@string/gender"
                android:textColor="@color/buttoncolor"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spUserRole" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgGender"
                android:layout_width="177dp"
                android:layout_height="91dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbMan"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/buttoncolor"
                    android:text="Erkek"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="676dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbWoman"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/buttoncolor"
                    android:text="Kadın"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="130dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="676dp" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: did you just forgot to post your logcats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you initializing the progress dialog here. I guess this is the error you didn't initialize the progress dialog before calling **show()**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ...............

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i have been searching my code for hours and it was simple as that. thanks. it is worked